# Why can't I pass someDep.changed directly to setInterval?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, this, meteor-tracker

Given the following code, why doesn't helper1 re-run, when helper2 does? I have a feeling it's something to do with the context that `.changed()` is called.

```
Template.example.onCreated() {
  var dep1 = new Tracker.Dependency(),
    dep2 = new Tracker.Dependency();

  Meteor.setInterval(dep1.changed, 1000); // doesn't work
  Meteor.setInterval( () => dep2.changed(), 1000 ); // works
});


Template.example.helpers({
  helper1: () => {
    Template.instance().dep1.depend();
    return new Date().getTime(); // never updates
  },
  helper2: () => {
    Template.instance().dep2.depend();
    return new Date().getTime(); // updates
  }
});
```

Comment: Passing in a bound version of the `changed()` function doesn't work either. :/

Comment: Doesn't work means it's not called or you get some error? If you get some error, it's probably caused by the changed context as you mentioned. Could you show more of your code?
Also if you haven't tried yet, you could bind your function like dep1.changed.bind(dep1).

Comment: `setInterval()` is a window bound function  so `Meteor.setInterval(dep1.changed,1000);` instruction makes the `this` in `dep1.changed` function reference the window scope. You should make setInterval(function(){dep1.changed()},1000) just like the next one you made with the arrow function.

Comment: @jakub, that was the solution! When I passed the bound function the first time, I was binding the onCreated's `this` instead of passing `dep1`